# how to match brackets in YACC

Tags: nested, match, yacc

in the LALR(1) parser, i know how to match the paired bracket, for example:

```
expr:   /* empty */

      | '(' expr ')'
      ;
```

can match the following input:

```
( ( ( ) ) )
```

but i am not sure how to write rules to match the input like this:

```
( ( ( ) ( ) )  ( )  ( ( ) ( ) ( ) ) )
```

this means there are many paired brackets inside a big paired bracket which are 
in the same level. one simple example like this:

```
( ( )  ( ) )
```

suppose there are many nested brackets, how to write the rules?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are looking at something similar to a lisp list then you would probably want to have a sub-expression for that purpose:

```
expr: /* empty */
    | expr '+' expr
    | ...
    | list-expr

list-expr: '(' expr ')'
         | list-expr '(' expr ')'
```

If you do not have other expressions (like the + shown in my example here) then you don't need to have a separate rule.

Note that will probably prevent you from having a function call defined with an expression:

```
expr: expr '(' expr ')'  // C-like function call not compatible
```

You could still have identifier calls such as:

```
expr: IDENTIFIER '(' expr ')'
```